# Expand query result in select where statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get all the values between two dates on the same table, but also, include the value immediately before the earliest one:

To be more clear, I have the following table (Table 1. with aprox. 46 million rows):

```
Table 1. (Table I have)
updatetime            | value
        .                   .
        .                   .
2018-01-01 08:32:02   |     2
2018-01-01 09:23:12   |     5
2018-01-01 10:45:00   |     8 * value to include on the result.
2018-01-01 11:10:44   |    10 * <-- earliest date.
2018-01-01 13:11:54   |    12 *
2018-01-01 16:14:57   |    16 *
2018-01-01 20:00:55   |    22 *
2018-01-01 22:34:43   |    23 *
2018-01-01 23:55:23   |    23 * <-- latest date.
2018-01-02 01:03:57   |    25
2018-01-02 03:39:07   |    28
        .                   .
        .                   .
```

I have accumulative values, so, the next value will always be equal or greater than the one before. I need to get all values between 2018-01-01 11:10:44 and 2018-01-02 01:03:57, but, I also need the value before the earliest date, that means that I need this result: (Table 2.)

```
Table 2. (Result I need)
2018-01-01 10:45:00   |     8
2018-01-01 11:10:44   |    10
2018-01-01 13:11:54   |    12
2018-01-01 16:14:57   |    16
2018-01-01 20:00:55   |    22
2018-01-01 22:34:43   |    23
2018-01-01 23:55:23   |    23
```

As you could see in Table 1, date spaces are not the same, so, previous date of the earliest date is unknown to me, and value incrementation is also random.

I already tried theese two queries, but I have doubts about performance:

The first one is just two queries made one, very bad performance because of the change of order of the table.

```
SELECT * FROM his 
WHERE updatetime>=(
  SELECT updatetime 
  FROM definition 
  WHERE updatetime<"2018-01-01 11:10:44" 
  ORDER BY updatetime DESC 
  LIMIT 1
  ) and updatetime<="2018-01-02 01:03:57";
```

The second should be slower than the first one, but if I define the column as incremental to make MySQL walk the table from the last value of the condition and not to walk all over it?

```
SELECT * FROM his 
WHERE updatetime>=(
  SELECT MAX(updatetime) 
  FROM definition 
  WHERE updatetime<"2018-01-01 11:10:44" 
  LIMIT 1
  ) AND updatetime<="2018-01-02 01:03:57";
```

Comment: Did you try with `UNION` ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for these queries to perform efficiently, you would need an index on column `updatetime` :

```
CREATE INDEX idx_updatetime ON mytable(updatetime);
```

One way to do it would to use a correlated subquery in the `WHERE` clause that selects the previous record :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM mytable t
WHERE 
    t.updatetime < '2018-01-02 01:03:57'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 
      FROM mytable t1 
      WHERE t1.updatetime < '2018-01-01 11:10:44' AND t1.updatetime > t.updatetime
    )
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r7FRBSeerAsSRSfDpNj5GK/0)** :

```
| updatetime          | value |
| ------------------- | ----- |
| 2018-01-01 11:10:44 | 10    |
| 2018-01-01 13:11:54 | 12    |
| 2018-01-01 16:14:57 | 16    |
| 2018-01-01 20:00:55 | 22    |
| 2018-01-01 22:34:43 | 23    |
| 2018-01-01 23:55:23 | 23    |
```

---

Another option is to compute the `updatetime` of the previous record in a subquery, and then use it to filter the table. This *might* perform better than the first query.

```
SELECT t.*
 FROM mytable t
 INNER JOIN (
     SELECT MAX(updatetime) updatetime 
     FROM mytable 
     WHERE updatetime < '2018-01-01 11:10:44'
 ) x ON t.updatetime >= x.updatetime AND t.updatetime < '2018-01-02 01:03:57';
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r7FRBSeerAsSRSfDpNj5GK/2)**